# Charge variable amount to subscription in authorize.net?

Tags: authorize.net

How can charge additional variable amount to subscription any time on authorize.net?

Through subscription, fixed amount can be charged to user subscription, whether there is a way, we can charge variable amount to subscription at any day until subscription is active?

Suppose I set amount $20 on every 10th of month to be charged from customer through recurring billing. Suppose, now I want $10 to be charged to customer on 2nd of month for other reason through his subscription, whether there is API available for that additional money to be charged?

Comment: sum with total amount.... not required??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with their ARB subscription API. You would need to combine CIM, which let's you create payment accounts on Authorize.Net's server, with your own payment engine. Then you can charge someone whatever you want, whenever you want, all while reducing your PCI scope.